# How to send SMS by SOAP API in PHP

Tags: php, api, web-services, soap, sms

I want to send an SMS message in PHP using SOAP API. I have the `username`, `password`, `to`, and `text` parameters.

I am trying to use this API: http://api.payamak-panel.com/post/send.asmx?wsdl

The method I am using is `SendByBaseNumber`.

```
Username    String  
Password    String  
text        []String    
to          String  
bodyId      Int
```

My code:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$api = new MelipayamakApi($username,$password);
$smsSoap= $api->sms('soap');
$to = '09123456789';
$smsSoap->sendByBaseNumber($text, $to, $bodyId);
```

Comment: Removed superfluous and redundant verbiage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see :
https://github.com/Melipayamak/melipayamak-php

sample code is here
A PHP wrapper for melipayamak's web services

Comment: I don't understand the codes because I haven't worked yet